# ZenDesk Chat on iOS: Test chat during development

Tags: ios, zendesk

I'm implementing ZenDesk chat functionality in an iOS application. During development, I obviously need to test the chat functionality between the mobile phone and the web interface to simulate communication between user and support.

When I launch a new chat without configuring it in any way, in the Zendesk Chat Dashboard, this will make a new visitor appear, which I'm betting is visible to support.

I have looked at the documentation for the Zendesk chat for iOS, but even though it was pretty thorough, I couldn't find anything there.

**Is there some way to make my simulated user only visible to me in the Zendesk Chat Dashboard, so I can test the chat functionality during development?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initiate the chat to your test user from the dashboard, or you could create a test department, add your agent to the department, then initiate the chat into that department.  Otherwise you may have to use a separate chat account for testing.

Comment: Thank you for very good suggestions! I was hoping for some more built-in testing feature, but guess I'll go for one of your suggestions.